# What is the diiference between library and framework?

Tags: frameworks

In progamming languages we listen many times that lilbray ,framewrok  etc . My question is What is the diiference between library and framework??

Answer (score 0):

Libraries provide developers with predefined functions and classes to make their work easier and boost the development process. When you use a library, you are in charge of the flow of the application. It is like going to Ikea. You already have a home, but you need a bit of help with furniture.
Framework, on the other hand, is like the foundation upon which developers build applications for specific platforms. A framework, is like building a model home. You have a set of blueprints and a few limited choices when it comes to architecture and design.